# The custom Icons have vanished from my google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps are quite new to me so any help would be appreciated.

I created a custom map width custom pins and shadows with an information window that pops up when the marker is clicked.

This was working fine up untill 2-3 days ago when the markers dissappeared, the shadow still shows in the correct place?

The map marker and shadow are in the same folder as the map so should both show, any help would be greatly recieved.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>  



function initialize() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51921,-0.07828);
                var settings = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);




var westendImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/WC1.png',
     new google.maps.Size(50, 55),
     new google.maps.Point(0,0),
     new google.maps.Point(23, 75));

                var westendShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/shadow.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(70,50),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(60, 48)
                );

                var westendPos = new google.maps.LatLng(51.52012, -0.13081);

                var westend = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: westendPos,
                    map: map,
                    icon: westendImage,
                    shadow: westendShadow,
                    title:"Westend Lettings Office",
                    zIndex: 2
                });

            google.maps.event.addListener(westend, 'click', function() {
                infowindow1.open(map,westend);
            });
```

Then show the map with:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:855px; height:390px;"></div>
</body>
```

Ok so I've answered my own question, google has updated the map api which of course has some bugs. So to fix my map icon problem I reverted to the previouse version 3.9.

Change the call to the api to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.9"></script>
```

Bravo Me! :)

The updated maps can now be found here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Please star or create an issue in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/), v3.9 is currently the frozen version, and will disappear when 3.12 (the next "major change) comes out, ~ 6 months. Possibly star [this issue (4630)](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4630)